# How to get data from image of ios image library?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a problem in my'project.
I need get data of one image of image library.
i had used uiimagepickerView but can not get data from image.
anyone please help me!

Comment: what do you mean by data . Is it nsdata or text present on image ? Please provide mere details .

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is about to convert the image to NSData.If I'm correct then you can convert the image picked by `UIImagePicker` to `NSData` using the following delegate of `UIImagePicker` :

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
         didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
         editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
   NSData* pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
}
```

Comment: This just to get image type png, but if this image not as... jpeg,jpg vv. I think can use it